# django checking for template but not rendering it

Tags: django

I have `url(r'^search/foo/$', 'foo'),` in **urls.py**

and

```
def foo(request):
    return render_to_response("suppliers/dashboard/calender.html") in **views.py**...
```

It actually going to the views file but not rendering the html file.... I know its going to the view definition because when i make the syntax error it shows there is an error.... Any help would be great

Comment: You're gonna have to post your entire view, but it seems your context dict is missing

Comment: what is your template path in your settings .py

Comment: You have a blank html page returned or what?

Comment: '/Users/Projects/ProjectName/AppName/templates'.. something like this....

Comment: Apologies... i got the answer it was problem with local setting file... Thank you

Comment: @user1529342: make your comment an answer, and then accept it when it lets you. Otherwise, the question remains open and clutters up SO.

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_response` format is as below

```
return render_to_response('shop/order_tracking.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'dict' : dict})
```